# Multiple 10+ Year Old Dell Desktop Computers Dying Before My Eyes - What's Going On / How to Retrieve Data?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-xp, data-recovery, dell-precision

I have more than a half dozen Dell desktops that are coming out of storage to restore the data on them.   They each work just briefly (minutes), then seem to die entirely.  What is causing this?  Most importantly, how can access the data on their disks?

I've never seen anything like this.

With each one of them, I turn it on, try to boot it, and get something close to normal function.   In some I've been able to login to Windows.  In some I got part way through the boot sequence.  With all of them, after the third or fourth attempt they end up in a state where they will not power on at all.  The little light on the power button no longer comes on.  Disconnecting the power, holding the power button for 30s as the instructions suggest produces no change.  Following Dell's troubleshooting that I've been able to find doesn't help.  The motherboard light still comes on, so they are clearly getting some power.

I've tried taking out the hard drives, and ordering something that can connect to them, but I can't find anything that connects and will read the data from these old drives.  They seem to have a variety of connectors on them to make things harder.

What should I do?

Will it be possible to read these old Windows hard drives if I can put them in the right kind of enclosure or use the right kind of connection?  So far, no success with this after trying 3 different kinds of hardware designed for this general purpose.

Is there some kind of hardware that's designed to basically read all different kinds of hold windows hard drives?

They were all fairly high-end workstations at the time, circa 2010 or older.  For example a Dell Precision 690, Precision T7400.

Thank you.

Comment: You should be able to use a standard carrier with a UBS connection. Put a drive in the carrier, plug in the AC, connect the USB to a working computer and see if you can read the data. Repeat, and then for non working drives, consider a local recovery agency.

Comment: Thanks John.  I'm looking at 4 different devices that are intended to connect to the hard drives.  Of them, 3 won't connect at all because the cable connectors don't quite match (there is a little tab that prevents a connector that would otherwise fit pin-for-pin from connecting).  The fourth connects, and the drive spins up, but then nothing shows up on the computer that it's connected to (windows or Mac).  Any further thoughts?  Thanks again.

Comment: You need to take the unreadable drives to a recovery agency to get the data from the drives (if they can). Use the fourth device for checking.

Comment: Precisions *might* have scsi or SAS drives - a picture of the drives in question would be of assistance - we don't see what you see so *clear* photos would be invaluable here . SAS connectors sometimes look similar to, but are incompatible with SATA

Comment: Probably obvious, but have you changed the CMOS batteries? I've had some machine over the years that just get "very weird" [I mean really unpredictable random fails] if the battery is down.

Comment: Thanks Tetsujin.  Yes, I tried this, but no improvement.  Can you think of other things that can make a whole set of similar-vintage computers all die following this pattern?  It seems like there is likely some component that they all share that has died on all of them.  Not sure what else might be a good candidate to try to troubleshoot.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, capacitors are failing.  Given the age of the computers you describe, it is likely that many of them are prone to the [capacitor plague](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_plague).  With motherboard problems, which can be caused by failed capacitors, I've seen the sort of "only mostly dead" behavior you describe.

Looking up the Precision 690, it appears that it supports both IDE and SATA drives, but I don't see a mention of SCSI or SAS.  Assuming that is the case, a device such as the "Kingwin EZ-Connect USB to SATA/IDE Hard Drive Adapter" would work well for recovering the data - it can connect to SATA, 2.5" IDE, and 3.5" IDE drives, and costs $20-$25.  I've personally used the USB 2.0 model for connecting 3.5" IDE drives.  It's not a permanent enclosure, but if your goal is to transfer data, it's great.